# How to adapt all() or any() into Pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was trying to filter Pandas Series by boolean like

```
df_2014 = df_m[('2014-12' >= df_m.index.to_timestamp() >= '2014-01')]
```

But this code worked

```
df_2014 = df_m[(df_m.index.to_timestamp() >= '2014-01')]
```

Seems like I cannot use more than two boolean in Series and this error caused

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

and I still don't figure out how to use any() or all() in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is something like this:

```
df_2014 = df_m[(df_m.index.to_timestamp() <= '2014-12') & (df_m.index.to_timestamp() >= '2014-01')]
```